# Lighttpd - url redirect or re write - gUP to IP

Tags: redirect, lighttpd

I would like to achieve the following in lighttpd
redirect the following:

http://192.168.0.5/test/ to go to http://192.168.0.9/test

and

http://123.124.125.156/test/ test to go to http://123.124.125.158/test/

both 192.168.0.5 and 123.124.125.156 are addresses of the server

I am going in circles with my current knowledge.

I will keep trying and report if i get it before a reply

Regards

Liam

OK found the solution

```
$HTTP["host"] == "123.124.125.156" {
    url.redirect  = (
        "^/test/(.*)" => "http://123.124.125.158/test/$1",
    )
}

$HTTP["host"] == "192.168.0.5" {
    url.redirect  = (
        "^/test/(.*)" => "http://192.168.0.9/test/$1",
    )
}
```

if you want to redirect everything the use this inside the redirect

```
"^/(.*)" => "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/$1"
```

I hope this help someone

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK found the solution

```
$HTTP["host"] == "123.124.125.156" {
    url.redirect  = (
        "^/test/(.*)" => "http://123.124.125.158/test/$1",
    )
}

$HTTP["host"] == "192.168.0.5" {
    url.redirect  = (
        "^/test/(.*)" => "http://192.168.0.9/test/$1",
    )
}
```

if you want to redirect everything the use this inside the redirect

```
"^/(.*)" => "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/$1"
```

I hope this help someone

Regards